# Delete all files in directory except .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, rmdir, delete-directory

I want to delete a specific directory on Windows. I use the code below. It works fine. I want to put the .bat file I made for this process in that directory. Naturally, the .bat file is also deleted. I want the .bat file to be excluded from this deletion. What should I do with the code?

```
Echo batch file delete folder
@RD /S /Q "D:\testfolder"
```

Comment: You cannot delete a directory if it contains a file, i.e your batch file. Unless you delete only files and not the directory, it will not be possible.

Comment: Thanks but I didn't understand you. The directory I want to delete has the files and my *.bat file. When i run the *.bat file with the above code, it works perfect. However, i want the *.bat file not to be deleted.

Comment: So you want to have your fridge thrown out as it is no longer wanted, but you have a beer in the fridge that you want to keep, but you want to keep it in the fridge. Is it possible to throw the fridge out without throwing the beer out with it?

Comment: So there are only 3 ways here. Either delete everything in the folder, keep the batch file and the folder itself if you want the batch file to exist in the folder, or copy the batch file out of the directory at the time of deletion, or best case would be to never store the batch file in the folder to begin with.

Comment: I don't want to throw away the fridge. I want to throw out all food and drinks except my water in the fridge. In the code I have already given as an example, the fridge is not thrown. It just empties its inside. 

What I want shouldn't be that hard. Forgive my ignorance.

Comment: I am not at a level to do these ways you say. Such as how to keep the batch file. How can i keep it anyway, i'm asking. I don't want to put the *.bat file in another directory.

Comment: The command you are using means REMOVE DIRECTORY. What do you think that means? You can't use the the remove directory command and expect the directory to remain and and a specific file inside of it.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was wrong. Actually it doesn't matter to delete that directory. It's important for me to empty the contents of that directory. Since the directory I am working on is an interactive directory, that directory has been recreated immediately. That's why I didn't notice. @Gerhard I understood you now. Thanks and forgive my ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve your task.

The method, (especially as you generally remove directories with one command, and delete files with another), is to identify the files and subdirectories separately. First identify the subdirectories and remove those, using the `RD` command, then delete all files except for the batch file itself, `%0`:

You could do that in one line using the `ForFiles` utility:

```sh
@%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "%~dp0." /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /C If @IsDir==TRUE (RD /S /Q @File) Else If /I Not @file == \"%~nx0\" Del /A /F @File"
```

Or you could use a `For` loop, with the `Dir` command:

```sh
@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('Dir /B /A "%~dp0"') Do @If "%%~aG" GEq "d" (RD /S /Q "%%G") Else If /I Not "%%G" == "%~nx0" Del /A /F "%%G"
```

*Please note that you can only remove/delete items for which you have the required permissions*.

Comment: I tried ForFiles utility above, it works perfect. This is what I wanted. Thanks

Comment: There is a problem with 'For \f' loop method. This method doesn't delete files with names containing non-English Latin letters. Words containing only English Latin letters are ok.

Comment: @Vuslatdemir, please provide one or more examples for me to confirm. Also please let us know what your current codepage is, i.e. open your Command Prompt window, type `chcp`, and press the `[ENTER]` key. _Could you also please consider marking your preferred solution as accepted_.

Comment: For example, if the files name is ask.txt, no problem. But if its name is aşk.txt Command Line says that "Could not Find C:\aşk.txt". **Ş** is a letter of some of the the Turkic languages. But I realized that this problem was only in few letters. For example there is no problem in Japanese and Russian alphabets. Also when i types chcp, it says "Active code page: 437". Forfiles utiliy has no problem. It works fine.

Comment: The issue is that you're not using the correct codepage for those characters @birisix, that is not a fault of the code I've provided! Those characters should work fine if you change the codepage to a more appropriate one, like perhaps `@%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com 857 1> NUL`.

Comment: I changed chcp to 857 and it was ok, works fine.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to lock your batch file, by opening a dummy read handle to it.

```
echo The batch file wont be deleted because it is locked by a dummy input redirection.
rd /s /q "D:\testfolder" 9<"%~f0"
```

Naturally, an error message will be shown by the `rd` command, because there is at-least one file in the target directory (your own batch file) which can not be deleted. You can hide that message by redirecting the standard error stream to the `nul` device:

```
rd /s /q "D:\testfolder" 9<"%~f0" 2>nul
```

Comment: At first I was thinking about something like this as well, but I dismissed the idea, because I am not sure whether `rd` still continues deletion; after a few tests however, I think this is going to work fine…

Answer (score 0):

I would walk through the items in the folder whose contents you want to delete, remove one after another, except its name equals the name of the batch file:

```
rem // Change into target directory:
pushd "%~dp0." && (
    rem /* Loop through immediate children of the target directory, regarding even
    rem    hidden and system items; to ignore such (replace `/A` by `/A:-H-S`): */
    for /F "delims= eol=|" %%I in ('dir /B /A "*"') do (
        rem // Check name of current item against name of this batch script:
        if /I not "%%~nxI"=="%~nx0" (
            rem /* Assume the current item is a sub-directory first (remove by `rd`);
            rem    when removal fails, try to delete it as a file (done by `del`): */
            rd /S /Q "%%I" 2> nul || del /A /F "%%I"
        )
    )
    rem // Return from target directory:
    popd
)
```

Comment: It works fine. But the code below shared by @Compo is much shorter, so I chose it. Thank you.

The short code that is: 

`@%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "%~dp0." /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /C If @IsDir==TRUE (RD /S /Q @File) Else If /I Not @file == \"%~nx0\" Del /A /F @File"`

Comment: @Vuslatdemir it is longer basically because of all the comments in the code.